# Excel Workbook freezes after saving it on Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I am developing an excel "application" that will be distributed to a few users, so it has a lot of macros/vba code on it. The workbook is about 2MB right now, so it's not incredibly big.

I was developing it on excel 2013, however my workstation had a problem and I had to work on it from a computer with excel 2010 for about a week. Problem is, when I came back to excel 2013, whenever I try to save the workbook(on excel 2013) it immediatly stops responding. When the program closes, excel is never able to recover anything and says the file is corrupted. The problem simply does not occur on excel 2010, where everything works perfecly and I can save it OK.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? I have tried removing a few sheets and saving the workbook afterwards, to test if a specific sheet was corrupted/causing problems, but even after I remove all the sheets from my woorkbook (and just leave a new blank sheet on it) it still freezes when I try saving.

It's important to note that the workbook in question uses a lot of excel features, meaning it has conditional formatting, defined names, activeX controls, shapes, formulas etc.

Comment: If you can remove all sheets then you might as well create a new Excel 2013 file and copy all macros over to the new file and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did what Ralph suggested and created a new excel file, then copied everything from the old workbook to the new one. Now it works fine. Apparently that was my only way out, the file was probably corrupted in some way.